# Google maps show wrong location on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API and it get lat long via hidden text box. Today it acting odd, it show wrong location on map, but if I write lat long manually for lat and long variable, it works good.

Html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ads-lat" id="ads-lat" value="35.68969456776873">
<input type="hidden" name="ads-long" id="ads-long" value="51.46769173739062">
```

Not working:

```
var long = document.getElementById("ads-long").value;
var lat = document.getElementById("ads-lat").value;
```

**[Not working](http://jsfiddle.net/f09bteov/9/)**

Working good:

```
var long = 51.46769173739062;
var lat = 35.68969456776873;
```

**[Working](http://jsfiddle.net/f09bteov/14/)**

Google code:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {
lat: +lat,
lng: +long
},
zoom: 15,
streetViewControl: false,
styles : styles, 
fullscreenControl: true
});
```

I have no idea why it acting like this, there is no error in console, also I checked with two different browser, it's not cache. As you see, it working when I write lat and long manually, it's kind of number/decimal, right? assuming it get value from input as string, but I write a plus sign `+` before variable, I repeat, there is no error about `not a number` from google. Any idea?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f09bteov/9/)**

It show somewhere in Russia (I think) but it's wrong, it should show somewhere in Iran, You can check lat long on [this](https://www.gps-coordinates.org/) website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

http://jsfiddle.net/f09bteov/19/

I did two things:
1) Changed `parseInt` to `parseFloat` (you were getting lat/lng of 35,51 ... ~170km area per degree, so a bit off),
2) Correct their order, and
3) Removed the `+` in your `lat: +lat, lng: +long` declarations. Not sure why they were there.

Comment: No, still is wrong location, it's Russia in your fiddle and it's wrong, right location is Iran. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/f09bteov/14/) is right.

Comment: Try this ... http://jsfiddle.net/f09bteov/19/ ... the lat/long variables were reversed

Comment: I used `+` and `parseInt` to turn string to number, but parseFloat save me.. Thank you. your fiddle need to update.